# Filtering an array based on the number of characters in each element using user-entered dimensions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm a very novice programmer and am a bit stuck on a practice assignment.

I want to learn to filter the elements in an array based on the number of characters in each element (my array is a list of 30 states). Basically the user enters dimensions (a number 0-40, and there is a min and max) in two text boxes and presses an enter button, then the array should change based on those numbers (removing elements that do not meet the entered specifications).

I have the HTML set up without problem, but am completely stuck on the Javascript. I was attempting to use "filter" but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post what your state list is?  I'm not sure what the numbers and min max are for or how you want to filter based on that.  Please provide what code you have in JavaScript.

Comment: You'll probably want to do something like `arr.filter(foo => min_len <= foo.length && foo.length <= max_len);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` function. It accepts one custom function which should return `true` or `false`. For example, this code takes `ints` array, creates a new array by applying custom function (removes even numbers), and assigns it back to `ints`:

```
var ints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ints = ints.filter(function(x) { return x % 2 === 1; }); // ints is [1, 3, 5] now
```

That's how you can use it in your case:

```js
// When a user clicks a button
document.getElementById('calc').onclick = function() {
  var strings = ['a', 'on', 'the', 'form', 'index', 'length', 'factory'];
  
  // Read values from <input>s
  var minLength = parseInt(document.getElementById('minLength').value);
  var maxLength = parseInt(document.getElementById('maxLength').value);

  // Filter strings array according to the rule (length is between minLength and maxLength)
  strings = strings.filter(function(x) {
    return x.length >= minLength && x.length <= maxLength;
  });

  // Output
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = strings.join('<br/>');
};
```

```html
Min length: <input type="text" id="minLength" value="0"/><br/>
Max length: <input type="text" id="maxLength" value="7"/><br/>

<button id='calc'>Show</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let s say your array is defined and it is called myArray.

I assume you can take the values from user in a way. So I randomly have chosen min and max as shown below.

```
var max = 40 , 
    min = 0 ; 

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length ; i++){
 var filteredArray = [];

 if( myArray[i].length >= min && myArray[i].length <= max ){

   filteredArray.push(myArray[i]);

 }

}
```